# Responsive images that don't line break

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive-images

Intro: I'm still learning, so please be gentle.

I'm trying to make my images scale responsively, and I want them to display sitting next to each other horizontally. I've made it work using white-space: nowrap; but it's apparently not well-supported. Are there any alternatives to this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

section.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.3125em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section.gallery h2 {
  display: none;
}

section.gallery ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

section.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0.3125em;
}

section.gallery li:nth-of-type(1), section.gallery li:nth-of-type(5) {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
    <h2>Our Puppies</h2>
    <ul class="puppies">
      <li><img src="img/pup_1.png" width="500" height="500" alt="3 week old sable puppy"></li>
      <li><img src="img/pup_2.png" width="500" height="500" alt="5 week old blue puppy"></li>
      <li><img src="img/pup_3.png" width="500" height="500" alt="9 week old black-and-tan puppy"></li>
      <li><img src="img/pup_4.png" width="500" height="500" alt="5 week old black-and-tan puppy"></li>
      <li><img src="img/pup_4.png" width="500" height="500" alt="5 week old black-and-tan puppy"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

[You can view what I have here.](http://www.public.asu.edu/~mrjone21/SunnyShepherds/index.html)

Comment: You can make a responsive layout, a three column grid that each takes up 33% of your container. Then make each image have a max-width of 100%. They will scale to their containers size and your images will become responsive. I'll write up an answer shortly.

Comment: does my answer help? If not, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking following view.

You can use `flex` to get it

working fiddle

**[fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/wqp2e4fb/)**

You can read here about flex [A complete guide of flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
section.gallery ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
}

section.gallery li {
  flex:1 0 0;
  padding: 0.3125em;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

section.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.3125em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section.gallery h2 {
  display: none;
}

section.gallery ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

section.gallery li {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 0.3125em;
}

section.gallery li:nth-of-type(1),
section.gallery li:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <h2>Our Puppies</h2>
  <ul class="puppies">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" width="500" height="500" alt="3 week old sable puppy"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" width="500" height="500" alt="5 week old blue puppy"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" width="500" height="500" alt="9 week old black-and-tan puppy"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" width="500" height="500" alt="5 week old black-and-tan puppy"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" width="500" height="500" alt="5 week old black-and-tan puppy"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use max-width and a responsive grid layout.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  width: 33.33%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```